# How to reverse the defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent "\"My user agent string\"" command

Tags: safari, defaults, web-browser

Using the `defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent "\"My user agent string\""` command, you can set the default User Agent for Safari. This means that the `CustomUserAgent` key gets written in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`.

```
<key>CustomUserAgent</key>
<string>My user agent string</string>
```

But how can you reverse this action? (Manually deleting the two rows from the plist doesn’t work, as they just get rewritten when Safari restarts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
defaults delete com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent
```